# Datadog client doesn't send trace to server

Tags: python, trace, datadog

I have following function:

```
def trace(request):
    caller_name = sys._getframe(1).f_code
    span_name = caller_name.co_filename+"/"+caller_name.co_name+":"+str(caller_name.co_firstlineno)
    if hasattr(request, 'span') and request.span:
        tracer_context = request.span
        span = tracer.start_span(name=span_name, child_of=tracer_context, service="pso")
    else:
        span = tracer.start_span(name=span_name, child_of=None, service="pso")

    request.span = span
    return request
```

I use it as following:

```
def my_func(request):
    request = trace(request)
    curr_span = request.span
    // some logic
    curr_span.finish()
    print(curr_span.pprint())
```

In logs I see spans as following:

```
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]       name my_func:66
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]         id 13718618561359452918
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]   trace_id 390415684220986929
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]  parent_id 1137199070532920484
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]    service my_service
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]   resource my_func:66
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]       type None
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]      start 1566218695.56
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]        end 1566218695.56
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]   duration 0.000800s
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]      error 0
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]       tags 
2019-08-19 12:44:55+0000 [-]            env:my-env
```

Agent works fine but on datadog server I don't see the trace. What is wrong?